# What are the best practices to write a log file on a web application?

Tags: logging

I'm currently creating a web application using node.js and I want to create log files. I want to know what the best practices are to create a log file. What fields should be included?
For example, if I have a function `foo()` called by the service `service 1` should I add something like that on the log file:

```
[ dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm:ss ] foo was called by service1
```

What are the suitable things to include in such a file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you are using nodejs then the best option for you is to use bunyan available here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan

This will do the date format etc.

Comment: To be clear: there is no "best option" - it's *your* best option. Best not to answer opinion-soliciting tool/framework questions. Further: you didn't address the original question asking what should be included in a log file (still off-topic as opinion-soliciting, but you answered the "what content to include" question with a framework recommendation).

Answer (score 1):

I use bunyan log, I found it easy.

1. Name log files with templates
2. Rotate to a new log file periodically (can also rotate on startup to
   clean old log files)
3. Rotate to a new log file once the main log file goes over a certain
   size
4. Keep a maximum number of archival log files
5. Delete older log files once the archive reaches a certain size
6. GZip archived log files

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/compare-node-js-logging-winston-bunyan/

https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan

Answer (score 0):

Good things to mention are the Datetime as you listed, any functions called, and any users who called them. Additionally, make sure you update the log on any constructors/destructors.

Equally print to it any PHP/Javascript/Sql errors.